Preparing bacon in stacks of multiple slices
I no longer have a cooker and I can't afford a new one for a long time. But my friend has an old, one person, George Foreman grill I can have.
Because of it's size I will have to stack my bacon slices (back bacon here in the UK) 4 slices thick (about an inch).  Will this cook through properly?
Is there anywhere I can find a time chart for it?

no times but check this answer https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4944/53013

While you could probably heat the stack through sufficiently, the exterior slices might be crispy, while the interior might be flabby.

Why not just cook in batches? I use a 4-serving Foreman grill for bacon all the time. At the very least, you'll want to rotate the slices every few minutes.
